# How to show a Twitter Widget on a Salesforce Login Page?

Tags: login, mydomain, widget, twitter

In the *My Domain* section of *Setup*, I am trying to utilize the *Right Frame URL* field to show a Twitter Widget in my login page.

Reference: http://www.peter-bender.com/easy-fully-branded-salesforce-login-page/
Here is a sample image from the reference website.

[image]

However, Peter Bender's article might be a slightly outdated. Browsers are now showing a message `Refused to display *<My Site URL>* in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'` if I inspect the element.

Searching for the error message did show many results on the sister website, www.stackoverflow.com. However, the solutions weren't related to Salesforce.

How can we troubleshoot the error and show a Twitter Widget on a Salesforce Login Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the same web page by Peter Bender, point five, second bullet:

Setup --> Sites --> Site Name --> Edit button -->

Clickjack Protection Level: Allow framing by any page (no protection)

--> Save button

Comment: Please do leave a comment if you think this drastically compromises on security.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the originally referred article has been removed.

I recently wrote a similar article that goes through all the currently required steps to set up a site and make it fit for showing on the right side of the salesforce login page:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/step-by-step-instructions-hosting-setting-up-login-page-guy-clairbois

Might be useful for anyone looking for a similar solution.